# Haskell "parse" not terminating for specific type of string

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing

```
parse' :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse' p inp = p `with` inp

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [a]
parse p inp = [ v | (v,[]) <- parse' p inp ]

mkMany1 :: (Parser a -> Parser [a]) -> Parser a -> Parser [a]
mkMany1 many p = do x <- p
                    xs <- many p
                    return (x:xs)

many1L :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
many1L = mkMany1 manyL

manyL :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
manyL p = (many1L p) ||| (success [])
```

I'm trying to parse a String for a number of substrings that doesn't include the characters `'<'`, `'>'` or `' '`(space) but my parser doesn't seem to terminate. Can someone give me some pointers on what I'm missing?

```
textValid :: Char -> Bool
textValid c =  c /= '<' && c /= '>' && not (isSpace c)      

text :: Parser String 
text = manyL (sat textValid)
```

When I try to run the following command, it never terminates.

```
parse (manyL text) "abc def <"
```

Comment: How are `many` and `manyL` defined? I suspect `manyL` gets stuck at the space.

Comment: sorry, it's suppose to be just `manyL`, I've added the definition for `manyL`

Comment: It's a classic parsing mistake to define `textValid` as _not_ something. You're allowing absolutely __any__ character that's not in`"< >"`, whereas you should specify exactly what you do allow - perhaps just alphanumeric values, starting with a letter? Anything goes is not good parsing. It's too easy to mistakenly match a separator that's enclosed in a string or similar error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `manyL parser` can succeed without consuming input (returning an empty list).

And one must not pass a parser that can succeed without consuming input as the argument of `manyL`, because in that case, you get precisely such an infinite loop as you are in.

After the first `text` consumed the `"abc"` prefix of the input, you are left with `" def <"` a `String` beginning with a space. So trying `text` on that, it consumes as many `textValid` characters as there are at the beginning of the `String` - namely 0 - and returns them - `[]`. That leaves the same input. Now `manyL text` tries `text` another time to see if that succeeds too ...

You should probably define

```
text = many1L (sat textValid)
```

so that `text` doesn't succeed without consuming input, and probably it is a good idea to consume spaces from the beginning of the remaining input after each successful parse, like

```
text = do
    result <- many1L (sat textValid)
    skipSpaces
    return result
```

(`skipSpaces` left to implement).